# Windscreen washer thing

Tags: subaru, leak, windshield-washer, outback

There is a hole in the part that holds my water for washing my windscreen on my 2003 Subaru Outback and I wanted to know is it expensive to fix this and can you do it yourself if you get a secondhand one from a wreckers?

Comment: Are you talking about the reservoir that holds the car's windshield washer fluid? They're usually made of nylon, and located in the engine compartment. If so, can you *see* the hole? If you can't see the hole, why do you think there is one? A leak is also possible from the rubber line(s) that connect to the reservoir, or from the small pump that's often mounted underneath the reservoir, or even from the reservoir cap if the cap is broken or missing.

Comment: Okay I didn’t know that. I know there is some sort of hole as the water doesn’t stay in the reservoir when I put it in there.

Comment: @Julie - Changing out the reservoir is *usually* not too hard, though some of them (I don't know about the Outback specifically) can actually be snaked around body panels, which makes it quite difficult to get out/in, or even to diagnose where a hole might be.

Comment: A problem is those in the junkyard are also brittle or otherwise have the same problem as yours . I had to buy a new one from nissan and it was $ 50 which is crazy but it is about the only choice.

Comment: @blacksmith37 thank you for your help and taking the time to give that